# Clear filter holder for the Canon 430EX III-RT?

Tags: canon, flash, filters

With my Canon 430EX III came a tungsten filter than neatly clips on to the flash head. However, it seems this is the only filter available.

I notice the Canon 600EX series comes with a clear filter holder that allows you to place a pre-cut gel inside.

Is there a clear filter-holder available to the 430EX III?  Perhaps from a third-party?  I've checked online extensively and can't find anything, so I'm assuming such a thing isn't available.  And, I can't see anyway to make or adapt one.  So, I figure it's back to sticking velcro strips to the flash head.  It's a shame as a clear filter holder would be a neat solution.

Comment: well, you could certainly make or adapt one: just take the amber filter, cut out the area that actually covers the flash diffuser, and glue in a piece of clear acrylic. That will give you a snap-on "clear filter". From there, you can make pre-cut gels to sit behind the clear holder you just made. Perhaps not _convenient_ or easy, depending on your DIY skills. But doable, I imagine.

Comment: If you don't want to go the velcro route, you can use any of the neutrally colored [slip on diffusers](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/909203-REG/vello_bd_c430ii_bounce_dome_diffuser_for.html) available [for the 430EX III-RT](https://www.amazon.com/Sto-Fen-Omni-Bounce-OM-EW-Diffuser-Speedlite/dp/B000CLNHXY) to hold the filter strips on the flash.

Comment: Canon even makes [an "official" one](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/bounce-adapter-sba-e2-for-430ex-iii-rt-speedlite) for the 430EX III-RT.

Comment: @scottbb  Unfortunately, the amber filter protrudes a fair distance from the flash.  To cut away the amber material so it would not cause a colour cast at the margins would mean removing so much of the filter that there would be anything appreciable left to work with.  I could tape over the amber bits, but then I'd be restricting the spread of the flash by doing so.

Comment: @MichaelC When I need to diffuse the light, that would work fine. However, more often than not, I don't use the flash diffuser.  Diffusers only really work well indoors.  Outdoors, where there's nothing to bounce the scattered light back towards the subject, a small diffuser only has a negligible effect other than reducing the output.

Comment: I was hoping some third-party manufacturer would have noticed this opportunity and produced a clear clip on filter. One problem that occurred to me is that the 430EX III recognises the amber filter is attached and adjust's the camera's white balance settings accordingly (presumably, and I would hope, only if the camera is set to Auto White Balance (AWB)). A clear filter would have to be so designed so the flash doesn't mistake it for the amber filter.

Comment: I just about have the skills to make a mould from the amber filter and to cast a clear one using some sort of acrylic resin. I'm very fortunate to have a wonderful shop close by that caters for that sort of thing.  However, the reward wouldn't be worth the effort. Velcro it is. Unless JJC step in to the fray that is.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MagMod (https://magnetmod.com/collections/packages/products/magmod-basic-kit2)

Kits have a lot of different gels and a gel holder that need not be used with any other modifier. (I say gel, but it's colored plastic).

Answer (score 0):

There are also other non clip-on filter sets available that might help you out. For
example the Rogue Filter sets which feature an elastic silicone band. There are also cheap knock offs, many of which work as well as the original.

[image: Rogue Filter Set]